# Which MTA don't have antivirus check for outbound emails?

Tags: email, antivirus

I need to test whether MTA has antivirus check for inbound emails. To check this I need to send email with e.g. EICAR testfile from another MTA to this one. However, Gmail, Yahoo and other well-known MTAs have antivirus check.

Does anybody know about MTA that doesn't check for viruses in outbound emails? I can create MTA for test purposes but using existing one is easier

Comment: In your mail client, configure the MTA-to-test as mail-server. Then just send an email to a domain the MTA is responsible for. The MTA will accept it without authentication because the email is for a domain, it accepts mails for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MTAs don't usually have AV built in, it's separate (though in some cases closely integrated, e.g. Exchange + Forefront).

I guess you're really asking which free webmail providers don't scan for viruses. No big provider is going to be that sloppy, and no small provider is likely to still be in business.

So you're probably out of luck with tis approach. Some alternatives:

- You could deploy your own MTA, as per Jeff's answer. This is less work than you'd think, since you aren't doing anything clever, so won't need to do any configuration; out-of-the box postfix will send a mail for you.
- You could fall back on the old messaging admin's trick and type SMTP commands by hand over telnet, but that's a little fiddly when you need to send an attachment.
- You could try using [SWAKS](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/).

I think SWAKS will be the best option: they have your exact use case - sending EICAR into an MTA to check the AV is firing - as one of the examples in their documentation!

Comment: Jeff makes the good point that deploying your own MTA is not a lot of work when you only want to send one non-fancy mail thru it!

Answer (score 3):

1. Fire up an EC2 micro instance.
2. Login and run `yum install postfix`
3. Open a port forward in your SSH client from port 1025 (or whatever you choose) to localhost:25 (forwarding destination is from the server's perspective).
4. Set your SMTP server in your mail client to be localhost:1025 (target address if from the ssh client machine's perspective).
5. Send mail as normal.

Simple testing server for 2 cents an hour. Costs you nothing after you delete it.