# Access to email without antivirus

Tags: malware, email, penetration-test, antivirus

I am doing a test where we want to asses whether an email with a benign virus in it, exits a network.

I need a means to receive the test emails I am sending from inside the network, without any antivirus or spam filters, and I need to receive them outside the network.

The problem is that all the online email services I have access to have anti virus protection, and will delete any messages sent from the network containing viruses before they reach my inbox. This makes it impossible to assess whether the emails where sent and received, and what viruses they contained.

Do you know of any email solutions (preferably online) without antivirus, or where I can turn it off?

I ended up setting up my own mail service on a server using pythons smtpd module and configuring mx records to point to my new service.

This solution is cumbersome to me and if you have an easier one, then please let me know.

Comment: You should first search the question before asking one, please see if this helps. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15327/which-mta-dont-have-antivirus-check-for-outbound-emails?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure of the question - if none of the e-mail you have access to can send a virus, doesn't this answer your question..? And if you're using an external online e-mail solution, doesn't it by definition live outside of the network?

Comment: @K.P. - so my problem is the opposite of your link. I need to check if it exits the network, making it outbound, not inbound.

Comment: @lorenzog - sorry if my question wasn't clear. Yes, online email services live outside the network, but their antivirus filters my messages without my control, and without alerting me, thus making it impossible to assess whether some email that might or might not have gotten filtered, contained a virus.

Comment: Did you even read the question in the link which I sent? It says "Does anybody know about MTA that doesn't check for viruses in outbound emails? I can create MTA for test purposes but using existing one is easier"

Comment: @K.P. - did you even read my reply to your first comment. I can copy and paste it in quotation for you, but I do not see the point.

Comment: @K.P. I think the OP wants to check if their network's SMTP server does outbound checks, not the MTA.

Comment: @lorenzog Does SMTP "Server" intended to do antivirus check, or we need to integrate something like ClamAV to do that? Will you correct me if SMTP Server = MTA+ MDA+ MUA+ LDAP + Spam Filter + Antivirus + something?

Comment: @K.P. the OP is probably the best person to answer this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a minimal UNIX VM somewhere on your network (e.g. an Ubuntu live on your workstation) and then use the `mail` command?

You might want to configure a basic mail transfer agent to correctly queue mail to your SMTP server. [Ubuntu uses Postfix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix), but there are many more such as [Qmail](http://cr.yp.to/qmail.html) and if you're brave, Sendmail.

Configuring a mail server is not an easy task and **it might break your company policy**. Make sure you're not doing anything contrary to your company's policies here.

Your solution with Python is also a good one.

And for a very, very basic solution there's also [telnet](https://serverfault.com/questions/38919/send-an-email-with-an-attached-file-using-telnet-or-netcat).